# Why does calling .cancel() in a animation listener cause a StackOverflowError?

Tags: android, animation, graphics

Is there some reason that I cannot call .cancel() on the Animator provided in an animation listener?

When I execute the following code I get a StackOverflowError:

```
        animation.addListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                if (!showCircles)
                    animator.cancel();
            }
        ....
```

Comment: What happens if you call `animation.cancel()`?

Comment: `animation` can not be called from within the inner class (unless it is declared final).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered a solution.

I found that you must call `animator.removeAllListeners();`, before calling `animator.cancel();`. (This is true for most all 4.0+ devices, but on the GSIII, for some reason, you do not need to.)

For some reason, the `cancel()` command was causing `onAnimationStart` to be triggered again (ending up in an infinite loop).

Comment: I wonder if this is an Android animation framework bug?! The reason I say this is that I found that the Galaxy SIII does not exhibit this behavior, but the HTC DNA and Moto RAZR HD do - so it seems someone at Samsung may have corrected this? I don't feel qualified to track this down, but would be interested to hear if anybody knows anything more about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think even though you are cancelling the animator the listener is still listening for the event.

I am not entirely sure if this will work but you could try adding :

if(animator != null) {
   animator.cancel();
}

I hope this helps

RF

Comment: I am sorry, but I spoke too soon. I am still seeing the StackOverflow.

Comment: I discovered a solution (which your answer led me to - I also discovered a bizarre wrinkle along the way.) Solution posted.